# Windows service can't be stopped

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a problem with a windows service. Sometimes service can't be stopped and hangs with a running status) after the start command with the message:
`The service cannot accept control messages at this time`

The simplified service implementation:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        protected object SyncRoot { get; } = new object();
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            lock (SyncRoot)
            {
                var task = PerformHealthCheck();

                while (!task.Wait(10000))
                {
                    RequestAdditionalTime(10000);
                }

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    //Some logic to start worker threads and initialize some startup processes
                    //All workers threads actually successfully executed.
                }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            //Code is not reachable sometimes
            lock (SyncRoot)
            {
                //Some stop logic
            }
        }

        private static async Task PerformHealthCheck()
        {
            int status = 0;
            do
            {
                status = CheckStatus();
                if (status == 0)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(20000);
                }
            }
            while (status == 0);
        }

        private static int CheckStatus()
        {
            //Calculating HealthCheck status
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Creation logic:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new Service());
    }
}
```

OnStart method is successfully executed till the end and OnStop method is not even hit. I can see the service status as following in WinDbg:

```
16 serviceType
4 currentState
5 controlsAccepted
0 win32ExitCode
0 serviceSpecificExitCode
0 checkPoint
0 waitHint
```

So apparently as far as I understand the service is in the Running state and has received the stop command but didn't execute it (I can see it from logs). I don't understand what could possibly stop the service from executing the OnStop method. Start command can be seen in windows event view but Stop command is not there.

Other information:

- .NET 4.5 Framework
- Windows Server 2012-2016

Comment: Sometimes this happens whilst developing a service and you attempt to deploy again when building.  Try restarting your computer to see if that fixes it.  (developing services in a VM is generally a good idea for this reason)

Comment: What is the code inside `//Some stop logic`, are you sure it's not stuck in there?

Comment: Try using the command line. "net stop [ServiceName]". There also "SC STOP [SERVICENAME]" & then
"SC DELETE [SERVICENAME]"

Comment: This is not happening on developer's environment. The user tries to update the software via MSI but the installer can't stop the service and when you try to stop the service manually you can see such a message.

Comment: I know how to stop the service the problem is why does it happen. And I'm 100% sure the the stop method is never hit because I have an internal variable at the beginning of the method and some logging lines just before the lock. I checked the variables in windbg, OnStop method was never hit.

Comment: Sounds like your startup logic is hanging, holding on to the lock that OnStop wants to acquire on entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example `PerformHealthCheck()` will run indefinitively. Thus your `OnStart` does never finishes. Don't know if that's only because of your simplified example.

However, do you actually log something when it happens? As in, log the end of the OnStart method and confirm that when the problem happens, the OnStart was actually finished. In your code-comment you write `//Code is not reachabl..` do you log something there as well? Or within the lock?

BTW, locking the startup and stop might seem like a good idea to synchronize, but as a user if i want to stop a service, i really want to stop it. Regardless of it still being in the state of starting up. In fact, if a service does not respond to the stop command, i suspect that 90% of the time, task manager is the next stop anyway... Is it not better if you try to rewrite the stop logic in such a way that it will always just executes and breaks off everything it can? This would probably solve your issue and also improves the experience imo.

Edit, it seems that the locks in fact don't do anything anyway (at least, if they are used only here and not to lock something elsewhere) The OS won't pass the OnStop command if its still StartPending..:

Is it possible that this happens when the startup just takes LONG and stop is called once BEFORE the start has finished? See this example:

```
class logger
{
    static readonly object _logSync = new object();

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        var m = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}; {message}{Environment.NewLine}";
        lock(_logSync)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\temp\test.txt", m);
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new TestHangService());
    }
}
class TestHangService : ServiceBase
{
    private logger _log;

    public TestHangService()
    {
        _log = new logger();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _log.Log("OnStart");
        Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
        _log.Log("OnStart exit");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _log.Log("OnStop");
    }
}
```

Then

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc create DeleteMe binpath="C:\testprojects\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe"
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc start deleteMe

SERVICE_NAME: deleteMe
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                            (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
    PID                : 27376
    FLAGS              :

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo "executed directly after starting"
"executed directly after starting"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc stop deleteMe

SERVICE_NAME: deleteMe
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo "waiting for 30 sec"
"waiting for 30 sec"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc stop deleteMe
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1061:

The service cannot accept control messages at this time.
```

which logs:

18:32:20; OnStart

18:32:50; OnStart exit

note not onstop

It will not recover from this it seems (which suprised me btw) even after 10 min:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query deleteme

SERVICE_NAME: deleteme
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc stop deleteme
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1061:

The service cannot accept control messages at this time.
```

Comment: It's a simplified example of course. OnStart is finished I can see it in logs and in Windows event view. I also log a lot of things including the beginning of the OnStop method before the lock of course and it's not hit. I had to use the company framework for the service creation, that's why locks are present. But again my problem is that for some reason OnStop method was never called but OnStart method is finished.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was really the case, the service was stopped before OnStart method is finished, causing the state corruption (can't accept any new messages, OnStop method is not called)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the running Pulse Secure Service could not be stopped when I wanted to remove the old version. I resolved it like this:

Go to Windows Start -> Administrative Tools -> Services

Find Pulse Secure.

Right click -> Properties -> Startup type -> Choose Disabled

Restart Windows

Uninstall the old version of Pulse Secure:

Start -> Windows System -> Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a program -> Uninstall it there

After that the new installation worked without trouble.